# Registration error, Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

Modify my registration blade. I added 2 additional functions that trigger the registration of the user. The data I needed are being saved to the appropriate tables but I am having this error,

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must
>   implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, boolean
>   given, called in
>   E:\wamp64\www\aftscredit-appzcoder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
>   on line 35

Here's my Registration controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Referral;
use App\CollectorMember;
use App\HasRoles;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');       
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $referral = '';
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $referral = Referral::where([
                         ['code', $keyword],
                         ['status', 0]
                         ])->first();        

        if (is_null($keyword))
            return view ( 'Auth.register');
        elseif ($referral)
            return view ( 'Auth.register', compact('referral', $referral))
                                    ->withDetails ( $referral )
                                    ->withQuery ( $keyword );
        else 
            return view ( 'Auth.register')->withMessage ( 'The code you provided is not EXISTING or not AVAILABLE.' );
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    } 

    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user_id = $user->id;

        Referral::find($data['referral_id'])->update ([
            'status'    => 1,
            'date_used' => $data['referral_date_used']
        ]);


        return CollectorMember::create ([
            'collector_id' => $data['referral_generate_by'],
            'borrower_id'  => $user_id,
            'referral_id'  => $data['referral_id'],
        ]);

    }
}
```

What's causing this? thanks in advance!

Comment: you are not returning the ```$user``` in create function

Comment: Thanks @AlanGe I just add "return $user" but when redirect me to /email/verify, the page is just keep on reloading...

Comment: There must be something wrong with your middleware assignation.

Comment: I guess the problem with email/verify is a different issue. Thanks @AlanGe! Your comment answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the `RegistersUsers` trait and look at line 35. A user is not being created.

The original Laravel controller code to create a user is as follows:

```
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Note how the DocBlock indicates an instance of `User` must be returned. This is key because the the actual code that completes the registration, within the trait, assumes a a valid User model instance.

It's sometimes helpful to step through the code and understand what Laravel is doing for you, behind the scenes.

Comment: thank you @zoider23! my problem with the original block is i don't know how i will be able to get the id of the newly register user in that structure that's why I put the user::create inside the $user variable.